# JBoss web: HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, netbeans, web, jboss, http-status-code-404

My JBoss AS7 is suddenly broke.
**HTTP Status 404 - /Aaa**

```
type: Status report
message: /Aaa
description: The requested resource (/Aaa) is not available.
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>MainPage.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/Aaa</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

It was working fine earlier. In console any errors are absent. `http://localhost:8080` and `http://localhost:9990/console` renders normaly.

Comment: Please have a look at the server.log. There should be a line stating that your application was deployed 'successful'. If not, try to find the first line in the log with logging level error or warn and post it here.

Comment: @siom 00:00:00,000 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "AAA.ear"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the deployment folder of JBoss. The servlet class should be there. If not, your compiling failed. If the class is there, restarting the JBoss service (eclipse, tab Servers, right mouse button on the server, restart) might solve the problem by forcing JBoss to reload the class files.